# How to do indexing properly in numba.cuda?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am writing a code which needs to do some indexing in python using numba.
However, I cannot do it correctly.
It seems something is prohibited.
The code is as follows:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
@cuda.jit
def function(output, size, random_array):
    i_p, i_k1, i_k2 = cuda.grid(3)
    if i_p<size and i_k1<size and i_k2<size:
        a1=i_p**2+i_k1
        a2=i_p**2+i_k2
        a3=i_k1**2+i_k2**2
        a=[a1,a2,a3]
        for i in range(len(random_array)):
            output[i_p,i_k1,i_k2,i] = a[int(random_array[i])]
output=cuda.device_array((10,10,10,5))
random_array=cuda.to_device(np.array([np.random.random()*3 for i in range(5)]))
size=10
threadsperblock = (8, 8, 8)
blockspergridx=(size + (threadsperblock[0] - 1)) // threadsperblock[0]
blockspergrid = ((blockspergridx, blockspergridx, blockspergridx))

# Start the kernel 
function[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](output, size, random_array)
print(output.copy_to_host())
```

It yields an error:

```
LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
'CUDATargetContext' object has no attribute 'build_list'
File "<ipython-input-57-6058e2bfe8b9>", line 10
[1] During: lowering "$40.21 = build_list(items=[Var(a1, <ipython-input-57-6058e2bfe8b9> (7)), Var(a2, <ipython-input-57-6058e2bfe8b9> (8)), Var(a3, <ipython-input-57-6058e2bfe8b9> (9))])" at <ipython-input-57-6058e2bfe8b9> (10
```

Can anyone help me with this?

One choice is to feed a also as an input of the function, but when a is really large like some 1000*1000*1000*7 array, it always gives me out off memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with array indexing. Within the kernel, this line:

```
a=[a1,a2,a3]
```

is not supported. You cannot create a list within a `@cuda.jit` function. The exact list of supported Python types within kernels is fully documented [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html#language).